# Why is 12 stored in register EAX in this 80x86 assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have this code:

```
section .data
Foos:
  mov ecx,7
  mov edx,5
L:
  inc edx
  sub ecx,1
  setZ al ; Set AL to 1 if zero flag, otherwise al=0
  shl al,1
  mov byte[L1+1],al
L1:
  jmp L
  lmp L
  mov eax,edx
  ret
```

What will be in [EAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#32-bit) at the end of the code?

I know it's 12, but why is the answer is 12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like self-modifying code.

It loops 7 times and when ecx reaches zero, it replaces the **jmp L** statement with a different JMP instruction which jumps to the statement after the second JMP.

```
Foos:
  mov ecx,7
  mov edx,5
L:
  inc edx
  sub ecx,1
  setZ al ; set al to 1 if zero flag, otherwise al=0
  shl al,1   ; multiply by 2, so al=2 when ecx reaches zero
  mov byte[L1+1],al
L1:
  jmp L
  jmp L
  mov eax,edx
  ret
```

The magic is in the **mov byte[L1+1]**. When al=0, it replaces the first JMP with a JMP to the next statement, which is again JMP L, so it loops.
When al=2, it replaces the first JMP to skip 2 bytes, so it skips the second jump, so the loop ends. At the end **edx** is 12 (5 + 7)

Why is that?

The JMP instructions used here are **short jumps**. They are coded as 2 bytes: **EB** followed by a single byte representing the relative number of bytes to jump. The **mov** instruction replaces the second byte by either **0** (jump to next instruction) or **2** (jump 2 bytes ahead).

Comment: I think most of the modern x86s won't see the instruction update.  By the time the "move byte[L1+1]" is executed, the code at L1 has been prefetched by the CPU into its instruction cache, and the update isn't seen by that cache.   This happens because it isn't worth the effort on the part of the CPU designers to make the interactions between self-modifying code and instruction caching work.   There are instructions to force a refetch of the instruction stream after such an update, but this code doesn't use them.   So this code loops forever ==> edx never has a value at the ret instruction.

Comment: Actually a modern CPU most definitely will see the instruction update.  When the mov byte[L1+1] retires, it will force a flush of the cache and the prefetcher and restart the instruction.  This has a huge performance impact, but it works.  It wouldn't do to have undefined behavior in legal code, would it?

Comment: Sorry for the tone of the last comment.  I can't see how to edit it, though.  I just read some comments on reddit, and I was in a foul mood.

Answer (score 1):

This code is self modifying and missing a memory fence instructions.  What happens depends on the processor stepping and how full the instruction cache is at the point when the code is executed which can change if this section of code is preempted by an ISR, a page fault occurs, or any number of other things.